# Example of lower bound on spectral gap for adiabatic quantum computing

Tags: resource-request, optimization, annealing, adiabatic-model

is there a list of reference for which the authors prove a lower bound of the spectral gap for an adiabatic quantum algorithm? I.e. I am searching for examples where the authors solve a problem with QUBO, but are also able to offer a runtime analysis based on the spectral gap. A list of 2-3 papers would be great already.
Thanks.